# Clock icon next to some apps on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, finder, applications, mojave, icon

Notice the clock or piece-of-pie icons next to 3 of the apps in this screenshot of the Finder. The icon has been there for two days. All three apps work; I have used each of them.

[image]

➥ What does that icon mean?

➥ Is it a problem? What can I do to fix it?

Using macOS Mojave 10.14.5 on a Mac mini (2018).

Comment: Are they always there, never advancing? Can you open and these apps? This icon is used, I think, when apps are being updated by the App Store. I know that Keynote and Pages were updated just a few days ago. If you have autoupdate apps configured, this may be happening in the background without you being aware of it.

Comment: @IconDaemon is correct, that's the icon when something is downloading.  It's not a problem.

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes, the icon sits there unchanged, with the tick mark just after noon (if this is a clock). Yes, all three apps launch successfully.

Comment: @fsb These apps are *not* currently downloading. The two Apple apps shown there, Numbers & Keynote, were updated the day before. But the *IntelliJ IDEA.app* was never downloaded from the Apple Store -- it was installed from an installer app.

Comment: The only time this icon is shown is when something is downloading or *was* downloading but was paused or interrupted.  It's not necessarily from App Store. You can make sure you're still connected to the internet and try rebooting to see if that helps.

Comment: Have you already tried restarting or relaunching the Finder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Bug

Apparently, the icons where caused by an innocuous bug.

After restarting the Mac mini, the icons were gone.

Answer (score 1):

I think those application are auto downloading any update or one of the downloading process has disturbed previously. Because of that the downloaded status is displayed as a % of the total download with that clock mark. You can see it with your self by simply adding a new download intentionally.